# What is the difference between lab Accreditation and Certification when selecting a drinking water test?

Tags: water

I need to test my drinking water and while researching labs in Virginia to send my water to, they designate some as [Accredited and others as Certified](https://dgs.virginia.gov/division-of-consolidated-laboratory-services/certification-accreditation/cert-accred/).

I am confused by the jargon to what is the difference between the two?

They both seem to need to adhere to the same EPA standards.

Comment: Would it be possible for someone to create the tag "water-test"?

Comment: A tag for water test... so for pressure or flow rate or temperature or hardness???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This may help](https://www.pbctoday.co.uk/news/planning-construction-news/accreditation-and-certification-difference/32133/#:%7E:text=Certification%20represents%20a%20written%20assurance,to%20work%20to%20specified%20standards). Without examples we can't provide be sure. Sounds like DGS does both in Virginia. Probably, they accredit the labs as following all standard operating procedures to be a competent lab *and* they certify that the test they use is sensitive to detect lead if lead is present, and specific when not.

> **Accreditation vs Certification**
> The terms accreditation and certification are often used interchangeably and occasionally together.  Despite the obvious confusion this can cause, the difference between the two distinct quality management processes can be easily explained.  Certification represents a written assurance by a third party of the conformity of a product, process or service to specified requirements.  Accreditation, on the other hand, is the formal recognition by an authoritative body of the competence to work to specified standards.  All accreditation standards include the principles of quality management systems, such as those found in the well-recognised ISO 9001 QMS standard.  It is the ability to demonstrate technical competence that puts accredited certification on a level above non-accredited certification.
>
> In effect, certification is the third-party endorsement of an organisation’s systems or products, while accreditation is an independent third-party endorsement of the certification.  The United Kingdom Accreditation Service (UKAS) is the national accreditation body for the UK.  Its role is to assess organisations that are providing testing, inspection, calibration and certification services (collectively known as conformity assessment bodies) against internationally recognised standards.  In the UK, if conformity assessment bodies are the watchmen, then UKAS watches the watchmen.
>
> Another crucial difference between accreditation and certification relates to the activities it covers.  Organisations receive accreditation for specific activities whereas certification relates to the company as a whole.  For example, if you are looking to test air leakage of a building it would be best to choose an organisation that has been accredited against the testing standard ISO 17025 rather than one that has a general quality certification of ISO 9001.  Further, the ISO 17025 testing activities themselves are tightly defined, so it is advisable to check the organisation’s schedule of accreditation closely; one that holds ISO 17025 accreditation for sound-proof testing would not necessarily hold ISO 17025 accreditation for air leakage.

Comment: Despite your answer being for the UK and the OP being in Virginia, USA, this is now an excellent answer, and _I_ think it would be applicable on either side of the pond.

Answer (score -1):

Accredited means that the "company" or lab has been accredited by a 3rd party.   Whether or not that 3rd party bears standing in the field is up to government agencies and sometimes jus the consumer.

Here we have labs getting accredited to work on water samples and provide analysis.

Certification is someone giving you something directly.   The parent teacher that accredits would not certify your water sample, the lab you sent it to would.   If the lab is certified or accredited it is basically the exact same thing.   There may be minute differences in lingo among industries, however I cannot see that being true for water testing, as it could be privately done and disputed but it is also regulated by US govt and most governments.

In laymen's terms if a lab is either accredited or certified in Virginia - there is no difference.   They should use the same testing methods and standards albeit I am sure certain labs are better or have better equipment.